# cloud function testing failing "Invalid request, unable to process."

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I have written a simple cloud function which I also deployed already to firebase and the code works. It is the following function:

```
exports.testfunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
     const mydata = JSON.parse(data)
     const mydata1 = JSON.parse({const1: "AAA", const2: "BBB", const3: "CCC"})
     return{mydata1}
 });
```

Now that I want to test this function localy, Im running the following command in my terminal: `firebase emulators:start` and I get no errors so far. Anyways as soon as I try to call the function with `http://localhost:5001/MYPROJECTNAME/us-central1/testfunction` in my browser, Im receiving the following error message which I can not find any workaround for:

> {"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

The thing is, the function itself is working great if I deploy it and call it from inside my app, but Im failing to run it from my firebase emulator inside the console.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091410/firebase-cloud-functions-statusinvalid-argument - answer your question?

Comment: @raina77ow It goes in the right direction. The answer over there suggests to add an argument to the call itself but how can I do this if I just copy paste the link in my browser?

Im sorry if this comment sounds little bit stupid, Im really new to this and its hard for me to understand those cloud functions.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [documentation for Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

> It's important to keep in mind that HTTPS callable functions are
> similar **but not identical to HTTP functions**. To use HTTPS callable
> functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with
> the functions.https backend API (**or implement the protocol**).

So, if you want to directly call the function via it's URL, your HTTP Request needs to follow the [protocol specification for `https.onCall`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

Comment: Im sorry but Im quite new to this topic and I cant figure out from the documentation what Im doing wrong. I understand your point and that HTTPS is different then onCall but I cant really understand what I should change (whether in my testfunction nor in my call which I execute in my browser) in order to make it work. Could you give me a little hint on what I should focus on?

Comment: Why do you need to call the **callable** Cloud Function via its URL? You should call it from your app, **via the SDK**. If you really need to call this function via it’s URL, modify it to an HTTPS one.